# Google OAuth/Google+ Api with multiple account

Tags: google-api

Spent the whole day to explore this ... api. But did not get the desired result.

Task - allow user login to my site with google account.

I have two google account. I want select what account use.

I read this [doc](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/)

But this not allow select account and use "default"

I try use gapi.auth.authorize({..., authuser: -1}). This allow select account but ... i must twice select account.

I can`t find documentation about /AccountChooser

How I can correctly login with select needed account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find next solution - my code [my blog](http://ase.com.ua/google-oauth-google-api-with-multiple-account.html)

I use this docs [Google OAuth API](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent?hl=ru)

Call **https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth** ton get **access_token**

With **https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=** get user details

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this problem on iOS, create a framework for it. https://github.com/Thywis/MultiAccountOauth

Basically, you have to sign in and restore the credential for multiple account, but I'm not sure why the Google iOS framework doesn't allow you to do this.